# C/C++ Как в памяти хранится long long?

Tags: c++, память

Решил тут с побитовыми побаловаться. Так вот: захотелось вывести все биты целого, но не делением, а побитами.

```
string s="";
    int x = 67542;
    for(int i=sizeof(int)*8-1; i>=0; i--)
       s += ((x&1<<i) ? '1' : '0');
    cout << s;
```

С int всё работает очень хорошо. Выводит 00000000000000010000011111010110
А вот что-то не так с long long(signed/unsigned). Выводит 0000000000000001000001111101011000000000000000010000011111010110
Вроде как повторяет число дважды. По идее должно выводить спереди кучу нулей.

```
string s="";
    long long unsigned x = 67542;
    for(int i=sizeof(long long unsigned)*8-1; i>=0; i--)
       s += ((x&1<<i) ? '1' : '0');
    cout << s;
```

Главный вопрос: почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь

```
(x&1<<i)
```

компилятор считает, что 1 у вас - это `int`. А должен быть `unsigned long long`, иначе просто будет UB при больших `i`.

```
(x&1ull<<i)
```

Попробуйте так...

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что `u` - `unsigned`, `l` - `long`?

Comment: @Danis Да, это в VC++ точно работает. Как в стандарте - точно не помню...

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
std::uint64_t number = 0xFFFFFFFF;
for (int shift = 63; shift >= 0; --shift)
    std::cout << ((number >> shift) & 1);
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111
```

Template:

```
template<typename T>
concept Integral = std::is_integral_v<T>;

template<Integral T>
void binrep(const T number)
{
    for (int shift = sizeof(T) * 8 - 1; shift >= 0; --shift)
        std::clog << ((number >> shift) & 1);
    std::clog << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Можно не писать свой `Integral`, есть `std::integral`.